# Integral of the question given in the body image

Tags: calculus, integration

![please help me to solve this one I think it must be converted in the format of sec
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rObiO.jpg)

$$\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{(1+\cos^2 x)\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x+\cos^4 x}}dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put $\cos x = t,$ then $\sin xdx = -dt$

$\displaystyle I = -\int\frac{(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+t^2+t^4}}dt = \int\frac{(1-t^{-2})}{(t+t^{-1})\sqrt{(t+t^{-1})^2-1}}dt$

put $(t+t^{-1})=u$ and $(1-t^{-2})dt = du$

so $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}du = \sec^{-1}(u)+\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Thnx this is right